# Wave equation with discontinuous initial condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Use the method of images to find the solution $u(x, t)$ to the initial-value problem
for the wave equation $u_{tt} = u_{xx}$ on the half-line $x ≥ 0$ with Dirichlet boundary
condition $u(0, t) = 0$ and initial data $u_t(x, 0) = 0$ and
$u(x, 0) = 1$ if $4 < x < 6$, $u(x, 0) = 0$ otherwise.

I know how to solve this for a continuous initial condition but I'm not sure what to do in this case. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This equation is linear; how about decomposing the initial data into its Fourier series and summing the solutions to the corresponding ivps?

Comment: extend the initial value $u(x,0)$ as an odd function to $x < 0.$ use $u(x,t) = \frac 12 \left(u_0(x - t) + u_0(x + t)\right)$

Comment: You look for the D'Alembert solution. This shows you how to deal with discontinuous initial conditions appropriately. To incorporate boundary conditions, you must use method of reflection.